# Baker miss block

Tags: baker

Aug  6 05:05:26 - 004-Pt24m4xi.client.baking: New baking slot found (level 552755, priority 0) at 2019-08-06T05:06:16-00:00 for bitcat after BKmTvZdzXLjX.
Aug  6 05:06:16 - 004-Pt24m4xi.client.baking: Waiting until 2019-08-06T05:06:53-00:00 (36.732s) for more endorsements in the mempool (30/32 arrived).
Aug  6 05:06:57 - 004-Pt24m4xi.client.baking: Injected block BKx2awb1dFDC for bitcat after BKmTvZdzXLjX (level 552755, priority 0, fitness 00::000000000109bdfe, operations 21+0+0+1).

My baker log show this info, Anyone know what happen ?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar experience yesterday...

Aug 08 18:11:52 xtz-baker tezos-baker-004-Pt24m4xi[28201]: Aug  8 18:11:52 - 004-Pt24m4xi.client.baking: New baking slot found (level 556259, priority 0) at 2019-08-08T17:12:44-00:00 for ledger_darren after BLStSJpPsxwu.
Aug 08 18:12:44 xtz-baker tezos-baker-004-Pt24m4xi[28201]: Aug  8 18:12:44 - 004-Pt24m4xi.client.baking: Waiting until 2019-08-08T17:13:21-00:00 (36.566s) for more endorsements in the mempool (31/32 arrived).
Aug 08 18:13:07 xtz-baker tezos-baker-004-Pt24m4xi[28201]: Aug  8 18:13:07 - 004-Pt24m4xi.client.baking: Injected block BMXUAvwMizu2 for ledger_darren after BLStSJpPsxwu (level 556259, priority 0, fitness 00::00000000010b7c73, operations 24+0+0+3).

I've now enabled --no-waiting-for-late-endorsements to see if this changes anything

Comment: I've never noticed this parameter. Thanks!